# can azure search do facets with one to may relationships

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

If I have documents (lets say books) I want to search that have a facet (lets say genre) where the document can have many values for that facet, so for example a book could be both "young adult", "fiction", "sci-fi"

Can azure search faceting handle this situation and if so can it do it from simple strings with a delimeter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the `genre` field in your index as a string collection (`Collection(Edm.String)` and make it facetable. When indexing documents, pass the values for that field as a JSON array:

```
{ 
  ... other properties
  "genre" : [ "young adult", "fiction", "sci-fi" ]
}
```